# Jquery appending element confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following javascript:

```
    $('#span_search').hide();

    $('#team_header').append($('<a href="#group-form" id="btn_new_category" class="btn btn-s-md btn-info" style="float: right;" data-toggle="modal">New Category</a>').hide().delay(500).fadeIn());

    $('#span_search').delay(1500).show();
```

Now i would assume that the span element would be visible later than the appended item but this is not the case... Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delay` works with only with functions that uses a queue for execution, where the execution of the next item in the queue is delayed till the timer is ran out.

`.show()`(without any argument) doesn't use a queue based execution, but methods that uses animation like `fadeIn()`, `slideToggle()` etc does.

One solution is to queue a function yourself which will display the content as shown below

```
$('#span_search').delay(1500).queue(function(){
    $(this).show()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3nLXk/)

or use a animated version

```
$('#span_search').delay(1500).fadeIn();
$('#span_search').delay(1500).slideToggle();
$('#span_search').delay(1500).show(1);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yd2aU/)

Answer (score 1):

It says in the jQuery documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

> ... this **will not** delay the no-arguments forms of .show() or .hide() which do not use the effects queue.

One big misunderstanding is thinking `.delay` will delay the functions chained after `.delay`. That is not true because `.delay` is used to delay the animation queue only.

To add a function into the animation queue, you can use [`.queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/):

```
$('#span_search').hide();
$('#team_header').append($('<a href="#group-form" id="btn_new_category" class="btn btn-s-md btn-info" style="float: right;" data-toggle="modal">New Category</a>').hide().delay(500).fadeIn());
$('#span_search').delay(1500).queue(function(){
    $(this).show();
})
```

or set the interval to zero:

```
$('#span_search').delay(1500).show(0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/egdtD/